# Is this valid C code

Tags: c

This does what I want but I don't recall seeing it anywhere before and was wondering if it's undefined behavior or is correct. I'm referring to how I pass the short to f().

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void f(short *s)
{
   printf("%d\n",s[0]);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    f((short[5]){0,1,1,1,1});
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is valid. The construction is called a compound literal, and was introduced in C99. Like any other literal, it's just a way to create a temporary array, for instance to pass to a function as in this example, without actually creating a variable.

Answer (score 6):

This is a special syntax known as "compound literals", and it is allowed since C99. It is discussed in the [C11 standard, section 6.5.2.5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5)

Answer (score 1):

`(short[5]){0,1,1,1,1}` is a compound literal of type `array 5 of short`.

When an array is passed to a function, it is converted to the address of the first element, which in this case is type `short *`.

As that matches `f(short *s)`, no more conversion is need as `s` gets a copy of that address.